# How to change filter labels in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony-1.4, filtering

How can I change filter labels in symfony 1.4?
My generator.yml has the following

```
filter:  
    display: [node_sub_type, organo_node_id, organo_position_id, employee_id]
```

so, it is showing "node sub type" in the menu. But I want to rename is as "Department". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an entry called `fields` inside `filter`, to force label for filter only.

```
filter:
  fields:
    node_sub_type: { label: Node subtype }
    organo_node_id: { label: Organo Node }
  display: [node_sub_type, organo_node_id, organo_position_id, employee_id]
```

If you want them to be global (in filter, form, list), you can add it globally:

```
config:
  fields:
    node_sub_type: { label: Node subtype }
    organo_node_id: { label: Organo Node }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hasan, just to add to your knowledge that you can also render the filter form fields seperately in _filters.php and put the label whatever you want. Alternatively, you can also assign label field in the Form Filter of that model.

For example,
$this->widgetSchema->setLabel('node_sub_type', 'Department');
$this->widgetSchema->setLabel('organo_node_id', 'ISD');